# merging 2 editing videos without saving them using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to combine 2 videos assume even they are edited among themselves

How normally we do

video 1:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter:a "volume=0.0" test1.mp4
```

video 2:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -filter:a "volume=10.0" test2.mp4
```

now I can combine them using

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -i test2.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] out.put.mp4
```

So my question is, Is there a way to make this 3 steps process into 1 step and without saving files of step 1 and step 2

I do know that we can combine into one using && but my main query is there a way to do without saving the files of video1 and video2 that edited files

Hope im a bit clear with my query

Comment: Answered at your off-topic crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67085953/
Please avoid crossposting. It can waste time for answerers.

Comment: @llogan sir am really sorry that I did update the question too please recheck once sir. can we do all these options also in the merge command(operations like change video Speed, resolution, rotation, framerate, and trim) if yes please share a command as example thanks a lot sir